# Pines notify icons not showing in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I'm using Pines Notify in my Rails 3 app, works nicely, except the icons are missing. Icons don't display at all.

I'm using the gem from 
https://github.com/navinpeiris/pnotify-rails

On further digging I discovered that the icons.css file which is present on the demo site is not present in the gem, nor are the icon images that it references.

Where do I get the icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up pulling the icons from the GitHub repo for Pines Notify:
https://github.com/sciactive/pnotify

For those looking for a solution, here's how I did it:
Fetch the original files from the pines notify repo:
https://github.com/sciactive/pnotify/archive/master.zip

Extract the file and then copy the icon files and stylesheet into your into your app, eg:

```
mv ~/Downloadspnotify-master/oxygen/icons.css app/assets/stylesheets/
mv ~/Downloadspnotify-master/oxygen/16 app/assets/images
mv ~/Downloadspnotify-master/oxygen/32 app/assets/images
```

Then add the icons css to your application manifest

```
*= require icons
```

Icons should work after that.

Comment: I download it but it has not files like icons.css

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I had the same problem and I was able to solve it using Font Awesome.
Add Font Awesome to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
```

Add this line before declaring Pnotify on your javascript:

```
PNotify.prototype.options.styling = "fontawesome";
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved in latest gem (3.0.0), just update your gem by running

`bundle update pnotify-rails`

and there will be no issue with icons.